# Speed up for loop with complex indexing in Python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I'm working on a program which has to compute a (covariance) matrix and the `for` loop implementation I'm using is quite slow. Numba complains about 4-dimensional numpy arrays and I wouldn't really know how to vectorize the code. Here's the code:

```
covmat = np.zeros((nbl, nbl, npairs_tot, npairs_tot))

for ell1 in range(nbl):
    for ell2 in range(nbl):
        for p in range (npairs_tot):
            for q in range (npairs_tot):
                
                if ind[p,0] == 0 and ind[p,1] == 0 and ind[q,0] == 0 and ind[q,1] == 0:
                    covmat[ell1,ell2,p,q] = (Rl*Rl*\
                    D_ALL[ell1, ind[p,0], ind[p,1], ind[p,2], ind[p,3]]*\
                    D_ALL[ell2, ind[q,0], ind[q,1], ind[q,2], ind[q,3]]*\
                    matrix[ind[p,2],ind[p,3],ind[q,2],ind[q,3]])
                
                elif ind[p,0] == 0 and ind[p,1] == 0 and ind[q,0] == 1 and ind[q,1] == 0:
                    covmat[ell1,ell2,p,q] = (Rl*Rl*\
                    D_ALL[ell1, ind[p,0], ind[p,1], ind[p,2], ind[p,3]]*\
                    D_ALL[ell2, ind[q,0], ind[q,1], ind[q,2], ind[q,3]]*\
                    matrix[ind[p,2],ind[p,3],ind[q,2] + zbins,ind[q,3]])

                elif ind[p,0] == 0 and ind[p,1] == 0 and ind[q,0] == 1 and ind[q,1] == 1:
                    covmat[ell1,ell2,p,q] = (Rl*Rl*\
                    D_ALL[ell1, ind[p,0], ind[p,1], ind[p,2], ind[p,3]]*\
                    D_ALL[ell2, ind[q,0], ind[q,1], ind[q,2], ind[q,3]]*\
                    matrix[ind[p,2],ind[p,3],ind[q,2] + zbins,ind[q,3] + zbins])
                    
                    # ... similar blocks
```

As you can see the task is further complicated by the `if` statements which check whether and where I should add the `zbins`
term (which is constant) to the indices of matrix. `ind` is just a 2d array used to store the correct indices.
Have you got any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: "Numba complains about 4-dimensional numpy arrays" um, what?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to us to do a working example, because this is a non reproducible question, please follow suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, it is impossible to understand how to use *ind*.

#### Hints

This seems a O(n^4) problem very hard to compute... numpy handle array very well, so start applying [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) to vectorize from the internal loop.
The condition becomes a mask and must have the same length as the q dimension.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the question is not very well-posed. I'll dig into the divide and conquer method, though